# vim autopopulate file

Tags: vim, automation

Is it possible to have VIM auto populate a file based on the extension?

For example, when I open a new `.sh` file, I would like VIM to automatically type

```
#!/bin/bash
```

as the first line.  (This example simplified down to the essentials)

Comment: This is a good question, I've often wondered this myself. I currently use Makefiles for this which I've always hated myself for.

Comment: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1160

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the section on "skeleton" in the vim help section:

```
:help skeleton
```

For your case, you should add a line like the following
to your .vimrc:

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.sh 0r ~/vim/skeleton.sh
```

Comment: Hmm.  I don't currently have ~/vim/skeleton.sh   Is that something I need to create (and populate)?

Comment: I can't seem to get this working. I've tried adding:

autocmd BufNewFile *.sh as well as ~/vim/skeleton.sh to my vimrc, but when opening new .sh files it echoes a message and then doesn't do anything.

Comment: @David Oneill: Yes, you need to give vim the template you want to use. What's it going to do, guess?

Comment: @b14ck: That's not an "or". That's `0r`, as in "read in the contents of this file at the zeroth line of the current file".

Comment: @Jefromi:  So the skeleton.sh in my case would just contain `#!/bin/bash` on the first line (if that's what I want in the file)?  [I didn't know if that was something it pulled from automatically]

Comment: Also is there a way to customize it? By example, on a C header file named foo.h the skeleton should something like:

/* ...License and stuff... */
#ifndef __defined_foo_h
#define __defined_foo_h

#endif

Which depends on the file name.

Comment: @David Oneill: It doesn't pull from it automatically. That's why you have to add this autocommand, telling it to read the contents of that file whenever you create a file named *.sh.

Comment: @Dacav: Clearly, with this approach, you're just reading the template in directly. If you want to do more, the answer depends on how you want to set it up. A very simple example would be to have the autocommand run: `0r ~/vim/skeleton.sh | %s/FILENAME/\=expand("%:h")/g` to read in the template, then substitute the actual filename (directories stripped) for FILENAME everywhere. For a very complex example (fancy templates) see bash-support-vim: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=365

Answer (score 1):

Vim can do this for sure, and more than what you expect.

Please refer to the popular "bash-support" plugin :

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=365

for details.